# Does libvlc.dll / libvlccore.dll support open and read timeouts?

Tags: vlc, libvlc

I am aware VLC incorporates ffmpeg internally, among other media libraries, and ffmpeg exposes two callbacks that receive calls when working with IP/network media streams: an open timeout and a read timeout. The open timeout is the time limit to establish the connection with a URL, and the read timeout is the time limit to read the next network packet.

Does ibvlc.dll / libvlccore.dll expose or support anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of stream are you trying to read? There are various timeouts options in libvlc that you can use. The list is here: https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

For example:

```
--rtsp-session-timeout=<integer> 
                                 Sets the timeout option in the RTSP session
                                 string
          Defines what timeout option to add to the RTSP session ID string.

--rtsp-timeout=<integer>   RTSP session timeout (s)
          RTSP sessions will be closed after not receiving any RTSP request for
          this long. Setting it to a negative value or zero disables timeouts.
          The default is 60 (one minute).

--ipv4-timeout=<integer [0 .. 2147483647]> 
                                 TCP connection timeout
          Default TCP connection timeout (in milliseconds)
```

Comment: Ah. I was looking for a callback or other programmatic hook. This makes sense.